# XML transformation using only IIS Web App Deployment On Machine Group task (YAML pipeline)

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a pipeline using only YAML.

I have defined the deployment part like this:

```
- stage: AzureDevOpsStaging
  displayName: Deploy build artifacts to staging environment
  dependsOn: BuildSolution
  condition: succeeded('BuildSolution')
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployArtifacts
    displayName: Deploy artifacts
    environment:
      name: AzureDevOpsStaging
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
            displayName: Deploy artifacts to IIS
            inputs:
              webSiteName: 'mysite-staging'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.zip'
              xmlTransformation: true
```

When I run this I get:

```
##[warning]Unable to apply transformation for the given package. Verify the following.
##[warning]1. Whether the Transformation is already applied for the MSBuild generated package during build. If yes, remove the <DependentUpon> tag for each config in the csproj file and rebuild. 
##[warning]2. Ensure that the config file and transformation files are present in the same folder inside the package.
```

Things that I've checked:

- Both Web.config and Web.AzureDevOpsStaging.config files are in the zip/artifact
- Name of stage - The docs say stage must have the same name as your transform config file; that is: Web.AzureDevOpsStaging.config.
- Name of .config transform file - the name of the .config transform file is Web.AzureDevOpsStaging.config
- Name of environment (the docs doesn't say the name has to be the same as Web.ThisPart.config but I still named the environment
  AzureDevOpsStaging just in case.)

But again doing all of the above results in the Web.config not being transformed.

I got it to work with using the file transform task instead which is referenced in the docs from the IIS Web App Deploy task:

```
- stage: AzureDevOpsStaging
  displayName: Deploy build artifacts to staging environment
  dependsOn: BuildSolution
  condition: succeeded('BuildSolution')
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployArtifacts
    displayName: Deploy artifacts
    environment:
      name: AzureDevOpsStaging
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: FileTransform@1
            inputs:
              folderPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.zip'
              enableXmlTransform: true
              xmlTransformationRules: -transform **\*.AzureDevOpsStaging.config -xml **\*.config
          - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
            displayName: Deploy artifacts to IIS
            inputs:
              webSiteName: 'mysite-staging'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.zip'
```

So can someone please explain to me how I am supposed to configure my YAML to get it to work  using only the IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0 task?

And if this is not possible am I using the task FileTransform@1 properly?

Also, I saw there is a version FileTransform@2 as well. That task didn't have one of the properties that @1 has so I reverted to using v1 instead. But would be great if someone has a bit more info on this newer version and if it's going to deprecate @1 in the future?

Btw, I also got xmlTransformation: true to work with classic release pipeline under the Releases tab in Azure DevOps using the UI. But again I don't want to use the classic stuff, I want to do everything in YAML.

Answer (score 0):

> And if this is not possible am I using the task FileTransform@1 properly?

The answer is yes.

The task `FileTransform` is the one I am using and use frequently.

When I use it in the YAML pipeline as you set:

```
      - task: FileTransform@1
        displayName: 'File Transform'
        inputs:
          folderPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.zip'
          enableXmlTransform: true
          xmlTransformationRules: '-transform **\*.UAT.config -xml **\*.config'
          fileType: xml
```

It works fine on my side:

[image]

In order to perform the conversion correctly, it is necessary to ensure that the syntax in config is correct, and the specified directory is correct

Comment: Have you tried getting it to work by only using IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0? I would be very interested in how you need to configure your pipeline & YAML to get it to work without FileTransform@1. If at all possible?

Answer (score 0):

Even do its some time ago this post was created. The magic thing that you need to do is to set the a value of `Release.EnvironmentName` variable used by the task. Default value is null when running a YML pipeline. It should have the same value as the middle part of your `web.<value>.config`

Se below example how you can copy value of `Environment.Name`.

```
    jobs:
      - deployment: Dev
        variables:
          Release.EnvironmentName: $(Environment.Name)
        displayName: development
        environment:
          name: Dev
          resourceType: virtualMachine
```

In your case it would look something like this

```
- stage: AzureDevOpsStaging
  displayName: Deploy build artifacts to staging environment
  dependsOn: BuildSolution
  condition: succeeded('BuildSolution')
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployArtifacts
    displayName: Deploy artifacts
    variables:
      Release.EnvironmentName: $(Environment.Name) #Name of the web.*.config file
    environment:
      name: AzureDevOpsStaging
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
            displayName: Deploy artifacts to IIS
            inputs:
              webSiteName: 'mysite-staging'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\*.zip'
              xmlTransformation: true
```